# Why doesn't my CSS load with my HTML??? I looked everywhere for the answer but can't find it

Tags: html, css

I've looked everywhere for the answer but cannot find it.  My HTML code works fine but the CSS does not load.  I have attached both below.  Thank you!

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            Home
        </title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300&family=Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <img src="pokeball-png-45330.png" height=100 alt="logo" class="logo">
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar">
                <nav>
                    <ul id="menuList">
                        <li><a class="nav" href= "/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav" href= "/celebrations">Celebrations</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav" href= "/fusion-strike">Fusion Strike</a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav" href= "/evolving-skies">Evolving Skies</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: #222;
}
```

Comment: Since you didn't specify a path to `style.css` this will assume it's suppose to be in the same directory as your HTML file, is it?

Comment: Just work fine for me. try use `<link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>` and put your CSS file aside to your HTML file.

Comment: yup, it's in the same directory

Comment: windows does this weird thing where it hides the extensions of files unless you turn it off in the preferences. check that the file is named "style.css" and not something like "style.css.txt" or "style.css.css".

Comment: In your browser press on F12 and look at the Console or Network tabs. There should be an error message. It could be an issue with how your site is hosted (I'm guessing on your local computer).

Comment: @Kobi ohh thank you very much, i see it. it says it failed to load the style.css and the pokeball.png. what could be the cause of this issue?

Comment: That means your style.css and image file is not loading into your HTML page.

Comment: @Damini Suthar i see, both the style.css and image file are correctly in the HTML page, is there a fix for the reason why it's not loading into the page?

Comment: Try to add like ` <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" >`

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT! I didn't know this because this is my first personal project and I'm sorry for not mentioning this before (I didn't know it was important) but I am using Flask.  For Flask, a "static" folder is needed that contains the .css and any .png.  Thank you so much to everyone!

Comment: No problem. In the future, you'd get a quicker answer if you include all information in the question (like the fact you are using flask).

Comment: @Kobi will do! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the snippet, your code works fine. Make sure that your `style.css` file is in the same directory as your html file.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>
    Home
  </title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@300&family=Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  Hi
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="pokeball-png-45330.png" height=100 alt="logo" class="logo">
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <nav>
        <ul id="menuList">
          <li><a class="nav" href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="/celebrations">Celebrations</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="/fusion-strike">Fusion Strike</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav" href="/evolving-skies">Evolving Skies</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```